# Sequelize/postgres: Get records matching a value inside an array of object with a provided value

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, select, sequelize.js

I have a db column which stores an array of object. An example value being:

```
[{
  "recordId": 11,
  "column": [{
      "name": "some value",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "other value",
      "id": "2"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "recordId": 12,
  "column": [{
      "name": "some value",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "other value",
      "id": "4"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Now, if i want to search record having `id:1` through sequelize, what should be in the `where` clause or is there another method to it?

Comment: Do you want a full sequelize solution, or you a raw SQL query would be an option?

Comment: @GMB anyone would suffice

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for rows whose json arrays has at least one object that whose `id` attribute has value `1`. In pure SQL, you would use `exists` with a correlated subquery that unnests the array:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.column) as x(obj)
    where (x.obj ->> 'id')::int = 1
)
```

Comment: @Gabriel: I have no knowledge in sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Op.contains`.

```
Model.findAll({
  where: {
    column: {
      [Op.contains]: [{ id: '1' }]
    }
  }
});
```

This will generate the following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM Model WHERE column @> '[{"id":"1"}]';
```